# Reg Expression to Validate Dollar amount greater than 0

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that validates dollar amounts greater than 0. I am using `^\$?([1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\-?\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))$|^\(\$?([1-9]{1}\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}\d{0,}(\.\d{0,2})?|0(\.\d{0,2})?|(\.\d{1,2}))\)$` which allows:

$1.00
1.00
1
$1.00
$1

but also allows
0
0.00
$0
$0.00

which I don't want. I thought having the [1-9] at the beginning of the expression would take care of this but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: depending on how generic you want it (all edge cases or not), it may be difficult. do you want `$?09`, `$?0.009`, `$?19099` etc. it may will be easy on the brain and maintenance of code just to pull all possible dollar values, cast to a numeric data type and test in a higher level programming language. have you provided all cases in your sample data

Answer (score 3):

At the bottom of this answer I've printed your regex in human-readable form, with some obvious mistakes corrected and irrelevancies removed.  It's composed of three top-level alternatives, which are all the same except the second one requires a leading minus sign, and the third expects the number to be enclosed in parentheses.  Since both are ways to match a negative number, and you want to match numbers greater than zero, I'll ignore those and concentrate on the first alternative.

The part of the regex that matches the actual number is composed of four alternatives, and as you can see, the third and fourth alternatives allow the number to start with just a zero before the decimal point, or with nothing at all.  If you get rid of those, your regex will match only values of at least one dollar.  But it still won't match positive values of less than a dollar.  Assuming you want to match those as well, you'll need to add another alternative, like so:

```
^\$?
(
  [1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?
  |
  [1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?
  |
  0?\.(?!00)\d{2}
)$
```

This is a complete regex for a positive dollar amount, with the dollar sign and the leading zero being optional.  If there is a decimal point, it *must* be followed by two digits.  In the third alternative, the negative lookahead `(?!00)` prevents it from matching `0.00` or `.00`, while still allowing fractional values like `0.01` or `.99`.

You can use the regex as it's written above by specifying `COMMENTS` or `VERBOSE` mode (or whatever your flavor calls it; they all have different names for it), or you can delete all the whitespace:

```
^\$?([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{2})?|[1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?|0?\.(?!00)\d{2})$
```

---

Below is the original regex:

```
^\$?
(
  [1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  [1-9]\d*(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  0(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  \.\d{1,2}
)$
|
^-\$?
(
  [1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  [1-9]\d*(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  0(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  \.\d{1,2}
)$
|
^\(\$?
(
  [1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  [1-9]\d*(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  0(\.\d{0,2})?
  |
  \.\d{1,2}
)\)$
```

Answer (score 2):

In python 2.7 (note that the sre.SRE_Match object indicates the string was found in the RE).

```
>>> cents = '0\.([1-9][0-9]|0[1-9])'
>>> dollars = '[1-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?'
>>> not_broke = re.compile('^\$?(' + dollars + '|' + cents + ')$')

>>> not_broke.match('$1.00')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b3b1880>

>>> not_broke.match('1.00')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b3b1918>  

>>> not_broke.match('1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b3b1880>

>>> not_broke.match('$1')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10b3b1918>

>>> not_broke.match('0.00')
>>> not_broke.match('0')
>>> not_broke.match('$0')
>>> not_broke.match('$0.00')
```